# file-type package loading server version with vitejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

Am using a [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) package and using [vitejs](https://vitejs.dev/) as my bundler, I keep on running into an error of `Buffer` undefined so I suspected vite making file-type loading the node version of it, am not sure but at this point am just out of ideas, I didn't encounter this problem when I was working with webpack, I just recently made the switch, am trying to avoid polyfills so any other ideas on how to resolve this will be highly appreciated.

P.S. I am using latest versions of both packages.